# How can I dynamically center the text inside of a button as it gets resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, frontend

When I resize the viewport, my button's text begins to leave the area of the button. If I add display:flex, justify-content:center, as well as align-items:center, then the entire button becomes shifted and is out of line with the list.

```css
.textList{
  margin-top:2vh;
  margin-bottom:2vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size:2vh;
  font-weight:700;
}
.btn{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:4.5vw;
  height:3.5vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;

  color:white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border-radius:1vw;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:1.75vh;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  

}
#listArea{
  position:absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  width:25vw;
  height:35vh;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0.75vw;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  border-image-slice:3;
  background:white;
  font-size:2vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="listArea">
  <ul id="divArea">
    <li class="textList">
      <input class="editField">
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the project: https://todolist.ibrahimshah.repl.co/

Comment: text-align: center;

Comment: @AdrianBrand He's already using that. That's not the issue, the size of the button is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I resize the viewport, my button's text begins to leave the area
> of the button.

You're already centering the text within the button with `text-align:center`. The text leaving the boundary of the button is not a centering issue, it's an overflow issue. As I always say, you can't put 10 gallons of water in a 5 gallon bucket. You should add a `min-width` to your button so it never gets smaller than its content. You should also consider adding a `min-width` to the `#listArea` to prevent the `li` and its contents from overflowing the box.

```css
.textList{
  margin-top:2vh;
  margin-bottom:2vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size:2vh;
  font-weight:700;
}
.btn{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:4.5vw;
  min-width:50px; /* <-- Don't let the button get too small */
  height:3.5vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;

  color:white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border-radius:1vw;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:1.75vh;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
#listArea{
  position:absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  width:25vw;
  height:35vh;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0.75vw;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  border-image-slice:3;
  background:white;
  font-size:2vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="listArea">
  <ul id="divArea">
    <li class="textList">
      <input class="editField">
      <button class="btn">Delete</button>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't imagine why a down vote for the correct explanation of the problem and a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways of doing this, the standard way would be to use text-align:center; but this only works on the horizontal axis, if you want to center the text both horizontally and vertically no matter the button size and shape, you can use flex positioning as shown in button example 2.

### Examples:

```css
.btn {background:#ff0000;color:white;font-size:20px;padding:8px 32px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:20px auto;max-width:600px;height:10vh;}

.btn2 {background:#ff0000;color:white;font-size:20px;padding:8px 32px;width:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;margin:20px auto;max-width:600px;height:10vh}
```

```html
<div class="btn">View More</div>

<div class="btn2">View More</div>
```

Comment: See my answer. Centering is not the issue here. You are also not showing an example of a `button`, which is what the question is about.

Comment: This example shows exactly what is needed in it's simplest form, the original question is highly bloated with unnecessary code, it's not much to expect that the OP should be able to figure out how to wrap the div with an <a> tag to make it into a button

Comment: @GibsonFX This example doesn't address the actual problem that the OP is facing, which is an overflow issue, not a centering one. And, adding an `a` doesn't make something a `button`, it makes it an `anchor`. A `button` or `input type="button"` makes something a button. And you could just look at the OP's code and see that he's already using `text-align:center`.

Comment: If the OP had followed the guidelines and presented code in a minimal reproducible example maybe the person answering could be expected to read the code, if not then it's the fault of the OP for misidentifying the problem.

Comment: @GibsonFX Whether or not the OP could have done a better job posting is irrelevant. This answer doesn't actually address the clearly stated problem of: *When I resize the viewport, my button's text begins to leave the area of the button.* And, the OP's code is not nearly as complex or bloated as you make it out to be. Sorry, but you haven't a leg to stand on here. This is not the answer to the question AND it doesn't even use code similar to what the OP is using in its attempt.

Comment: The title is **"How can I dynamically center the text inside of a button as it gets resized?"** to which this is an answer, the OP should title their questions correctly if they want accurate responses. A more appropriate title would have been **"Button text overlapping container when viewport resized"** and okay it makes it an anchor if you want to argue semantics over functionality, but the OP could just change `div` to `button` or `input type=button` which is even easier. You could have been way more helpful by simply editing the answer slightly before downvoting it

Comment: @GibsonFX First, you should NEVER edit someone else's answer beyond grammar formatting. Changing the fundamental code is a big "no-no". Second, it is so common here for OPs to not be experienced enough to articulate their problem. It is OUR job to read and understand the questions. If JonHutch did, he'd have seen the fist line of the question's body and he'd have seen the `text-align:center` already being used in the code. There is literally nothing in this answer that addresses the code that the OP has shown or the actual issue. You're just wrong on this one. Good luck to you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm sorry you feel my answer wasn't helpful, you are right I should have taken more time to read the question properly, but a heads up before slapping me with a downvote would have been appreciated. I'll happily adjust my answer to be more correct if you'd consider removing your downvote, stack doesn't exactly make it easy for new contributors trying to help out as it is, without high rep members slapping you with downvotes for honest mistakes.

Comment: @JonHutch Don't take it personally. The down vote is a way for the community to grade the quality of an answer as it is and is an incentive for people to post better quality answers. If you do a down vote can always be retracted and I'm happy to do that if that happens. When you give a down vote, it's always good to comment to that person why you did it, as you can see I did way up at the top of the comments.

Comment: @JonHutch You may want to read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), specifically the part about "Answer the question" (you too @GibsonFX)